# How do I stop MediaMonkey from forcing itself as the device's default AutoPlay behaviour?

Tags: music, autorun, music-management, mediamonkey

Whenever I plug my phone into my computer, MediaMonkey opens with it and starts to scan the device for music. The usual way to disable this behaviour is via the AutoPlay menu under the Control Panel, but *MediaMonkey overrides even this*, rendering any user-made changes from the Autoplay menu under the Control Panel pointless.

**How do I disable this intrusive default behaviour?**

Comment: Did you ask MediaMonkey support?

Comment: I didn't. I wouldn't usually get in touch with a company over something like this cause it's usually easier to sort it out myself.

Comment: Well it seems like a bug in their software so you should report it.

Comment: Hmm, a bug didn't even occur to me. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infuriatingly, not only does MediaMonkey make itself the default Autoplay application for your device, it also reaffirms this setting each time you plug your device in, effectively riding roughshod over the user right to control how your device connects to your computer. In addition, I couldn't find any option in MediaMonkey's own settings to disable this behaviour.

**After changing and saving the option in the Control Panel:**

[image]

**Immediately after reconnecting the device:**

[image]

I couldn't determine what exact registry key(s) MediaMonkey uses to do this with Process Monitor, but here's how to disable the behaviour entirely.

## Stop MediaMonkey from thrusting itself onto AutoPlay

1. Connect your device to your computer, and close MediaMonkey.
2. Open the Device Manager by typing it into the Start Menu's search bar.
3. Find your device under Portable Devices, right-click it and select Uninstall. This will uninstall your device's driver.

[image]

4. Disconnect your device from your computer, then reconnect it. Once reconnected, Windows will automatically attempt to find a driver for it, which has the byproduct of restoring its default Autoplay functionality.

Comment: What happens the *next* time you connect a device after the driver has been reinstalled? Does mediamonkey do it's autoplay trick again?

Comment: @Twisty - Once the driver's been uninstalled and installed, MediaMonkey stops making itself the default AutoPlay behaviour, so it stays at whatever you set it to. In my case, that's "Ask every time".